# How to clear specified format data from clipboard?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I put some data into clipboard , after I copied data from the clipboard, I want to clear the data without clearing the entire clipboard.

Something like that:

```
wchar_t* buf=NULL;
if( OpenClipboard(NULL)!=0)
{
HANDLE hData = GetClipboardData( CF_UNICODETEXT );
buf = (wchar_t*)GlobalLock( hData );
GlobalUnlock( hData );
CloseClipboard();
return buf;
} 

//job is done, and now I want to clear only hData!
```

As far as I understand, EmptyClipboard() will empty everything!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

The clipboard only holds a single `IDataObject` at one time; this data object can present multiple data formats but it is just a single COM object. The only way to do what you want would be to duplicate the existing data object (minus the format you wish to remove) and set that to the clipboard in place of the original.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, a how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I needed it, so I coded it, "empty then refill minus what I want to delete", crashes at times, the real InsideClipboard.exe doesn’t crash, so I must be something wrong

https://github.com/FuPeiJiang/InsideClipboard.ah2
gui, not a library/function
Ahkv2, close enough to C

edit: CF_BITMAP,CF_ENHMETAFILE,CF_PALETTE are HANDLE, not memory addresses, (reason for the crash)
I needed a gui, but maybe someone needs C code, so:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <winuser.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "User32.lib")

typedef struct FORMAT_AND_DATA {
    UINT format;
    HGLOBAL data;
} FORMAT_AND_DATA;

void deleteClipboardFormat(UINT format) {
    OpenClipboard(GetClipboardOwner());

    FORMAT_AND_DATA *format_and_data = malloc(sizeof(FORMAT_AND_DATA)*(CountClipboardFormats()));

    size_t i=0;
    UINT clip_format = 0;
    while ((clip_format=EnumClipboardFormats(clip_format))) {
        if (clip_format==format) {
            continue;
        }

        HANDLE src = GetClipboardData(clip_format);
        if (GetLastError()) {
            continue;
        }

        size_t size;
        HGLOBAL copy = src;
        if (src==0) {
            //delayed rendering
        } else {
            switch (clip_format) {
                case CF_BITMAP:
                case CF_ENHMETAFILE:
                case CF_PALETTE:
                    //handle
                    break;
                default:
                    //memory
                    size = GlobalSize(src);
                    copy = GlobalAlloc(0x2, size);
                    void *dst=GlobalLock(copy);
                    memcpy(dst, src, size);
                    GlobalUnlock(copy);
                    break;
            }

        }

        format_and_data[i].format = clip_format;
        format_and_data[i].data = copy;

        ++i;
    }

    EmptyClipboard();
    for (size_t j = 0; j < i; ++j) {
        SetClipboardData(format_and_data[j].format, format_and_data[j].data);
    }
    CloseClipboard();

    free(format_and_data);
}

int main() {
    // I don't know if these numbers change so replace with your numbers
    deleteClipboardFormat(49338); // HTML FORMAT
    deleteClipboardFormat(49562); // text/html
    deleteClipboardFormat(49459); // image/svg+xml
    //-really inefficient, code your own to take an array of formats as input
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering why would you want to do this. I am not an expert in Windows programming, but I will try to answer anyway because it seems to me that this question has been left "orphan" and I might provide some insight (hoping I am not spectacularly mistaken).

As far as I understand, the clipboard is meant to hold several *alternative* representations (in different formats) of *one* entity.

What is the use case for removing only *one* such representation? I would say what makes sense is either remove all the representations (through `EmptyClipboard()`) or none.

Probably you are thinking that the clipboard is meant to hold *several entities* of different type, and this is why you are looking for a selective removal. I'm afraid that is a misconception, and does not reflect the real purpose of the clipboard.

Comment: There are many use-cases where removing specific formats from the clipboard would be very useful. Just because you can't imagine such cases doesn't mean that others don't need them.