# How to change clipboard data in Windows

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, clipboard

I have the following clipboard data:

[image]

Can I somehow change indexes of these records?

Also can I remove / make zero-length some of them?

Is it possible via WinAPI?

As for the first question, I don't see any function for this purpose.

As for the second question, I wrote the following code:

```
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
  OpenClipboard(NULL);

  HGLOBAL hdst = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE | GMEM_DDESHARE, sizeof(int));
  int* dst = (int*)GlobalLock(hdst);
  dst[0] = 0;
  GlobalUnlock(hdst);

  SetClipboardData(49166, hdst);

  CloseClipboard();
}
```

but it didn't zeroed the record of the 49166 format.

How can I do it?

Comment: [How to clear specified format data from clipboard?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14419197/how-to-clear-specified-format-data-from-clipboard)

Answer (score 0):

This is a method to do that. First, obtain the clipboard data string   by use `GetClipboardData` api, and then modify the data string by your way. Second, rewrite string to cliboard by use `SetClipboardData` api.

You don't call `GetClipboardData` first from you code, you can do that like this:

```
char *buffer = NULL;
CString fromClipboard;
//open the cliboard
if (OpenClipboard())
{
    HANDLE hData = GetClipboardData(CF_TEXT);
    char* buffer = (char *)GlobalLock(hData);
    fromClipboard = buffer;
    //modify fromClipboard string by your method and rewrite to clipboard
    //maybe like this
    fromCliboard.Replace("hello", "world");
    HGLOBAL clipbuffer;
    char* buffer;
    EmptyClipboard();
    clipbuffer = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_DDESHARE, source.GetLength()+1);
    buffer = (char*)GlobalLock(clipbuffer);
    strcpy(buffer, LPCSTR(source));
    GlobalUnlock(hData);
    GlobalUnlock(clipbuffer);
    SetClipboardData(CF_TEXT,clipbuffer);
    CloseClipboard();
}
```